# convergence for a function of normal variates

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say we have a sequence of zero mean normally distributed random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$, where $cov(X_j,X_k)=\sigma_{jk}\neq 0$ and $var(X_j)=\sigma_j^2$. Then where does $$\frac{1}{\frac12(n^2-n)}\sum_{j>k}X_jX_k$$
converge to?

Comment: What mode of convergence are you interested in? Convergence in distribution? Convergence in probability? Complete convergence? Almost-sure convergence? Mean-square convergence?

Comment: Many thanks for the comment. I will be happy with any results here, but primarily convergernce in probability makes me very happy :-)

Comment: With no hypothesis on the covariances and variances, basically anything can happen. You might want to restrict the question to the case that really interests you.